# Dual boot Ubuntu 12.04/Windows 7

Tags: 12.04, dual-boot, system-installation, live-usb, boot-repair

I have an Ubuntu 12.04 / Windows 7 dual boot. After installing Ubuntu my computer reboots straight to Windows. There is no option to boot Ubuntu.

Specs:

- OS: Windows 7 Home Premium
- CPU: Intel i5 2500k
- mobo: ASUS P8Z68-V Pro
- GPU: GeForce GTX 570
- SSD: Corsair 120GB (Windows 7)
- HDD: WD 1TB

I select the USB drive in the BIOS and boot to it and choose install. I select to manually configure partitions, partition the 200 GB of unallocated space on my 1 TB HDD into 16 GB swap file, 30 GB `/` ext4, and 154 GB `/home` ext4.

I made sure that the bootloader is installed on the Corsair 120GB SSD (where the Windows boot is) and the installation goes smoothly.

When I reboot after the install it runs through the BIOS straight into Windows. I have tried upwards of a dozen times and I have also tried with Linux Mint. I have also redownloaded the ISO and used two different programs to create the live USB.

The installation seems to have gone well, as after the installation I can see the partitions I have created in Windows Device Manager.

[image: screenshot of Windows Device Manager showing Ubuntu and Windows partitions]

I currently run Lubuntu on my laptop, but it is not a dual boot. I'm assuming this is a bootloader issue and I am assuming that inside those partitioned files in my screenshot there is a working Ubuntu 12.04. I just have no way of getting to it.

---

Update: (copied from comment)

I booted using my Ubuntu live USB and used the Boot-Repair tool suggested in [virpara's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/145340/52923).

Upon opening the tool I saw that it was recognizing my SSD as a removable drive and defaulting to install on the HDD. Once I realized that I was able to force install onto the SSD. My computer can now boot Ubuntu.

Comment: Yes they do and it looks much better, Thanks :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you should re-install grub.
check my answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/142750/after-installing-ubuntu-from-usb-grub2-cant-be-installed/142751#142751). It is done through GUI tool.

By the way I don't like to give link to answer but it doesn't worth just copy and paste it again and again.

Comment: yes i did see that but how do i reinstall grub from linux if i cannot boot to the linux i installed? if i reinstall from a live USB will it have the same effect?

Comment: Yes it will - though I do not like that tool - it has caused some people issues. I used the information here - https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Installing#Reinstall_from_the_LiveCD

Comment: @Alkatraz boot into live cd and follow steps.

Comment: @Elfy that page is really fantastic. I often check it but recommend use of GUI tools for new user.

Comment: So do I if I know there's no problems - obviously ymmv:) When I was a new user I used to fix things that way - no GUI.

Comment: UPDATE: i booted to live usb and used the tool virpara suggested, upon opening the too i saw that it was recognizing my SSD as a removeable drive and defaulting to install on the HDD. once i realized that i was able to force install on the SDD and now i am posting this from my freshly installed Ubuntu 12.04


Thanks for all of the help you guys rock!

Comment: @Alkatraz I'm glad it helped you.

Answer (score 0):

I also posted an [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/141463/39869) to a question that's really similar to yours.

If you saw nothing after you chose the GRUB Entry that means your GRUB didn't install properly.

Comment: it will work only if `grub2` is installed on `sdaX` rather than `sda` and if OP wants to use windows boot loader.