# Auto booting in to windows every time I shutdown from Ubuntu

Tags: boot, dual-boot, windows-8

I upgraded to Windows 8.1 and used [this tutorial](http://www.everydaylinuxuser.com/2014/05/install-ubuntu-1404-alongside-windows.html) to fix my computer so I can boot into Ubuntu.

But for some reason every time I shutdown Ubuntu, the next time I turn my computer on it auto boots up into Windows. But when I boot into Windows, shut down, and turn my computer back on, grub2 shows up and I can choose Ubuntu. I tried installing updates for Ubuntu, and updating grub2.

Does anyone know what's going on?

Comment: The other thing you could try is to modify the Windows bootloader[1] instead of using grub.


  [1]: http://superuser.com/questions/499617/how-can-i-add-linux-to-the-new-windows-8-boot-manager

Comment: Have you read through [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/145335/dual-boot-12-04-windows-7-after-installation-my-computer-reboots-straight-to-win)?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem putting Ubuntu onto a Windows 8 computer.For some reason Winblows uses several partitions, and I think that's part of the problem. I solved the problem by installing Win 7 (the customer didn't like Win 8), then Linux. Winblows always overwrites the boot sector, mark the main Win 8 partition so you can recognise it, then install Linux, and tell Grub to write to that drive, hopefully that should fix it.

Comment: I already have Linux installed on the machine. The problem started happening when I upgraded to Windows 8.1 and then did that fix from above.